# Calling setState from a child event in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to redraw my UI whenever the app receives data from a serial device (using the usb_serial package).

```
TextEditingController cntrl = TextEditingController();
...
ListView(
children:[
                     TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          port = await _deviceList[0].create();
                          bool? openResult = await port?.open();
                          if (!openResult!) {
                            SmartDialog.showToast("Failed to connect!");
                            return;
                          }
                          port?.setPortParameters(
                            globals.baudRate,
                            globals.dataBits,
                            globals.stopBits,
                            globals.parity,
                          );
                          SmartDialog.showToast("Connected!");
                          port?.inputStream?.listen((Uint8List event) {
                            setState(() {
                              _cntrl.text=utf8.decode(event);
                            });
                          });
                        },
                        child: const Text("Start"),
                        style: startButtonStyle,
                      ),
   TextField(
     controller: _cntrl,
   ),
],
)
```

but the UI is never redrawn. I searched a lot on the web on what should be done if I have to call setState() from a child event but couldn't find any answers. What could be the solution?

**Edit:**
Apparently it was just some weird bug, I copied the same code to a new project and it started working like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to pass a function to the child, for example:

```
class MyChildWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onRefresh; // The callback that will be called to refresh parent state

  const MyChildWidget({Key? key, required this.onRefresh}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => onRefresh(), // Call the callback when button is tapped
      child: Text('Refresh Parent'),
    );
  }
}
```

Now when using the `MyChildWidget`, you can pass in `onRefresh` parameter and let that do `setState` in the parent, for example:

```
MyChildWidget(
  onRefresh: () => setState(() {}),
);
```

This would be an easy way to do some simple state management. When things get too complicated, you could look into some more advanced state management solutions such as `StreamBuilder` or the `provider` package.

---

**Update:**

With your updated question, the problem is not at `set state`. Maybe the your `input stream` did not emit events. You could try to add `print` statements to check if the stream is working.

Try this much shorter code to test the concept of "set state to a TextField", and you should see it's working as intended:

```
final _controller = TextEditingController();

// ...

Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    TextButton(
      onPressed: () => setState(() {
        _controller.text = 'Hello World';
      }),
      child: const Text('Set text'),
    ),
    TextField(
      controller: _controller,
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: I don't have a child widget, since my UI is pretty basic and I am trying to achieve a basic functional prototype, I am just trying to update a textfield whenever the port listens to new data, thus I need to setState for the whole page widget

Comment: @TheCoder what are you trying to refresh? In your question, you said you want to refresh the whole app, and you are already using setstate to update `_text` variable. You didn't include code that uses the `_text` variable.. might be a good addition to the question.

Comment: Done, pardon the poor formatting since I had to post part of my entire code

Comment: I did try printing and the event does get emitted but the UI doesn't update

Comment: @TheCoder well... if you run the short demo I posted, you should see the text field does update.. so, it's probably something else in your app.

Comment: I think you missed it but I am using setState in port.inputStream.listen inside the onTap event and I think that is causing issues

Comment: @TheCoder That's not an issue, make sure the event is firing, and the data you receive is actually something non-empty.

Comment: I did try printing the data and even showing a toast from the event and its all happening, but for some reason the UI is just not updating at all